# Having trouble understanding what I am doing wrong with my SQL Joins

Tags: codeigniter, join

I have recently been trying to beef up my query skills and to do so, I decided to make a simple twitter clone. I have two tables I am trying to join.

**Users table**
User_ID Pimary key
Username
Email
Etc...

**follow Table** (For following users)
ID Pimary Key
FK_Follower (Foreign key to User_ID) UNIQUE
FK_Followie (Foreign key to User_ID)UNIQUE

My logic here is that every row must have a unique pair eg(16,18|18,16|14,13) and whenever a user requests to follow, If the row already exists, I remove it. This allows for boolean like functionality.

I am creating a view for a users followers (You go to the users page and click view followers and it shows you who is following them)

Naturally, to accomplish this I know I need to use a join between User table and Follow table. I am using codeigniter for query building but the structure is very easy for anyone with sql knowledge to tell what is going on so it looks like this

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('follow');
  $this->db->where('follow.FK_Followie_ID', $id);// look for all rows where someone follows the user $id value passed to this function
  $this->db->join('users', 'users.User_ID = follow.FK_Follower_ID' ,'right');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
```

In my view I then call upon the row values I need and display them, (Done this for global feed, specific profile feeds, and individual feeds So I know it is nothing in my view logic)

Using the Right join is the only way I can display results however, they are wrong. I am positive I am sending the query the right $id value that pertains to the profile page being used but I have tried every combination of joins under the sun and the only time it displays results, they definitely aren't right.

Can I accomplish what I am trying to do? Is this an issue with perhaps my table structure? Or is it just my query logic? I have a feeling there is a gap in my join knowledge that I need to square off if someone would be so kind to enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```html
    $this->db->select('*');  
    $this->db->from('follow');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.User_ID = follow.FK_Follower_ID' ,'right'); 
    $this->db->where('follow.FK_Followie_ID', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();  
    return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @kundanPicker Ive tried this query many times to no result. It ends up showing everyone in the db who has subbed to someone.